For some test cases which have large input size i am getting error as 'abort called' or 'session ended' for this code in python
def minion_game(string):
    l=[]
    stuart=0
    kevin=0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(string)+1):
            l.append(string[i:j])
    for i in l:
        if i[0].lower() in 'aeiou':
            kevin+=1
        else:
            stuart+=1
    if stuart > kevin:
        print('Stuart', stuart)
    elif stuart < kevin:
        print('Kevin', kevin)
    else:
        print('Draw')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)

This code is working for small size of string inputs but not working for strings which have large size like more than 500 or 1000

You need to copy/paste the actual whole error message into the question.

You also need to explain what the code is supposed to be doing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
